# Drupal: detect elements in viewport + statistics

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, viewport, user-tracking

Motivation: detect elements (view's divs) in viewport on scroll + ignore iterations + collect to DB + show statistics. Is there any solutions? Or just give me directions. I'll be very grateful. No results with my searches, no ideas (Google Analytics - NA).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use Google Tag Managers "Element Visibility" trigger.

This lets you fire off an event when a certain percentage of an element is within a users view. It also has options such as "firing once per page" or "per element".

You can then use Google Analytics to show statistics on these events.

I found [this](https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/how-to-track-scroll-depth-element-visibility-in-gtm/?#how-do-you-track-element-visibility-in-gtm) article which covers the feature.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, i know this method. And i think it's only one solution now for me. But i can't use it. Views' blocks dynamic, statistics integrates with Drupal too difficult in this case.

Comment: I don't really understand what your blocker is, but I can imagine some scenarios. I might get around some problems by running some custom JavaScript that's firing with Drupal behaviours; that would let me react to any interactions that other modules might be initiating and potentially manually fire analytics events. Might also need to use some hook on the backend to add some markers to the dom elements....good luck!